# Accurate timer using python time [on the microseconds level]

Tags: python, time, clock

I want to create trigger that runs something every 500 ms, and it should be without drifting over time.
I have this code running to show something in pyopengl

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.t_on = time.clock()
    ...
def display_gl(self):
    ...
    if (time.clock() - self.t_on) >= 0.500:
        self.t_on = time.clock()
        #do things
    ...
```

the clock is drifting over time, I think that's because the `if` condition is catching the 500 ms moment after a little time.

Is there any way to avoid this drifting issue?

**Solved**:
changed:

```
if (time.clock() - self.t_on) >= 0.500:
    self.t_on = time.clock()
```

to:

```
if (time.clock() - self.t_on) >= 0.500:
    self.t_on =time.clock() - ((time.clock() - self.t_on) - 0.500)
```

Comment: check the time of your if statement then deduce if from 500ms, so the new time+ process time is exactly 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**:
thanks to [Mayeul sgc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4350650/mayeul-sgc) 
changed:

```
if (time.clock() - self.t_on) >= 0.500:
    self.t_on = time.clock()
```

to:

```
if (time.clock() - self.t_on) >= 0.500:
    self.t_on =time.clock() - ((time.clock() - self.t_on) - 0.500)
```